# Combine 2 aggregate queries: display results in single row (DB2)

Tags: db2

First query

```
SELECT count(*) AS TAXTOTAL
FROM T_tx_tax_report rpt
  INNER JOIN T_TX_TAX_REPORT_TRANSACTION trans
    ON rpt.TAX_REPORT_ID = trans.TAX_REPORT_ID
WHERE rpt.created_ts < '10/01/2015'
      AND trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE NOT IN ('MIGR')
GROUP BY (rpt.created_ts), trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE, rpt.TOTAL_WAGES
ORDER BY (rpt.created_ts) DESC, trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE ASC
```

Second query

```
SELECT count(*) AS TAXTOTAL
FROM T_tx_tax_report rpt
  INNER JOIN T_TX_TAX_REPORT_TRANSACTION trans
    ON rpt.TAX_REPORT_ID = trans.TAX_REPORT_ID
WHERE rpt.created_ts = '10/01/2015'
      AND trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE NOT IN ('MIGR')
GROUP BY (rpt.created_ts), trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE, rpt.TOTAL_WAGES
ORDER BY (rpt.created_ts) DESC, trans.TAX_REPORT_SOURCE ASC
```

The created_ts condition in the WHERE clause is the only difference between the 2 queries. Combine the queries to show the result in one row. THANKS.

```
            No. Prior to             No. On
             10/01/2015               10/1/2015           Total No.      
 a                     5                    1                   6
 b                     10                   3                   13
```

Comment: mmhhh you need editing. It is just terrible -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simply add up occurrences where one or the other condition is true, something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
  ...,
  sum(case when rpt.created_ts < '10/01/2015' then 1 end) "No. Prior to date",
  sum(case when rpt.created_ts = '10/01/2015' then 1 end) "No. On date",
  count(*) as "Total No."
FROM    T_tx_tax_report rpt
INNER JOIN T_TX_TAX_REPORT_TRANSACTION trans 
ON rpt.TAX_REPORT_ID =      trans.TAX_REPORT_ID
where   rpt.created_ts <= '10/01/2015'
...
```